# How to model the probability function in a “weighted” sum of conditional means?

Tags: probability-distributions, normal-distribution, conditional-probability, conditional-expectation

Assume $X$, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are normally distributed random variables. Define $Z$ as $Y_1+Y_2$, but $Z$ is either $Y_1$ or $Y_2$: in other words, $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are mutually exclusive and there’s uncertainty about which, among the two, $Z$ is. I want to compute $E[X|Z]$.

The conditional mean should be:
\begin{align} E[X|Z]&=E[X]+\frac{\operatorname{Cov}[X,Z]}{\operatorname{Var}[Z]}(Z-E[Z])\\&=p(Z)E[X|Z=Y_1]+(1-p(Z))E[X|Z=Y_2]\\&=p(Z)\left(E[X]+\frac{\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y_1]}{\operatorname{Var}[Y_1]}(Y_1-E[Y_1])\right)+(1-p(Z))\left(E[X]+\frac{\operatorname{Cov}[X,Y_2]}{\operatorname{Var}[Y_2]}(Y_2-E[Y_2])\right) \end{align}

My only unknown is the probability $p(Z)$: how do I model it? The probability $p(Z)$ depends on the realization of $Z$. For example, is it a linear function in $Z$? Why or why not?

I want to capture the idea that there’s a probability $p$ to observe $Y_1$ and a probability $1-p$ of observing $Y_2$, but $p$ itself actually depends on the “size” of the observation $Z$ (e.g., the larger $Z$ is the more likely it is that $Z$ is $Y_1$ rather than $Y_2$ or similar lines of reasoning). How to model this idea in the simplest way?

Comment: Your model is a bit messy, you should first clarify it. You start by saying $Z=Y_1 + Y_2$, then you rectify and say it's either one - you can do this with a Bernoulli random variable $B$ and set $Z=B Y_1 + (1-B) Y_2$. But finally, you also say that $Z$ depends on the size of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ - for instance, you could either have $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ with very different mean and/or variance (easy) or say that $B$ depends on $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ (not so easy). My suggestion is that you first try to come up with a clear model or, even better, start from the simplest one and then increase its complexity.

Comment: I totally agree with you that my wording could be confusing. I am still thinking how to frame my ideas into a model. 

You write: "you could either have Y1 and Y2 with very different mean and/or variance (easy)". Yes. This is the source of the asymmetry in $p(Z)$. So?

The basic idea is that I am an agent who observes $Z$ but can't tell whether what I observe is $Y_1$ or $Y_2$. Accordingly, I form some beliefs about it. Based on the size of $Z$, I assign some probability to $Z$ being $Y_1$ rather than $Y_2$ (asymmetric chances). How about $p(Z) = 1 / (1 + exp(-kZ))$. Would it help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this will answer your question, but I hope you can get some hints on how to formulate your problem properly and on how to tackle it.

Let's start by introducing some notation: let $X\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_X, \sigma^2_X)$, i.e. $X$ is a normal random variable with mean $\mu_X$ and variance $\sigma_X^2$. Similarly, $Y_1\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_1, \sigma_1^2)$ and $Y_2\sim \mathcal{N}(\mu_2, \sigma_2^2)$. Also, let $\rho_{X,1}$ and $\rho_{X,2}$ be the correlation coefficients between, respectively, $X$ and $Y_1$, $X$ and $Y_2$, so that, for instance $\operatorname{Cov}[X, Y_1]=\rho_{X,1}\sigma_X\sigma_1$.

Next, we have a new random variable $Z$, which we define as
$$
Z = BY_1 + (1-B)Y_2
$$
where $B\in\{0,1\}$. Although I'm not completely sure, what I understand from your [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802824/how-to-model-the-probability-function-in-a-weighted-sum-of-conditional-means#comment10214732_4802824) is that you'd like a way to infer the value of $B$ from the observation of $Z$ - let's see what we can do.

A general framework for this type of problems, for if you want to look into it, is that of *[hypothesis testing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_hypothesis_testing)* and *[detection theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detection_theory)*. We start by defining two hypotheses, the *null hypothesis* $H_0$ and the *alternative hypothesis* $H_1$, as
\begin{align}
H_0 &: B=0 \text{ or, equivalently, } Z=Y_2 \\
H_1 &: B=1 \text{ or, equivalently, } Z=Y_1.
\end{align}
Then, after observing $Z$, we'd like to make an educated guess as to whether $H_0$ is true or $H_1$ is. Keep in mind that, for this problem to make sense, we're also assuming that the distributions of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are different - just to focus on a simple practical case, let's say that $\mu_1 > \mu_2$ but $\sigma_1^2 = \sigma_2^2=\sigma^2$.

### Case 1: $B$ is a parameter

In the first case we are going to consider, $B$ is just a parameter, meaning that it is fixed to either $0$ or $1$, although we don't know its value. In this case, a common approach is to look at the likelihood function
\begin{align}
L(b|Z=z)=p_{Z;B=b}(z)
\end{align}
where $p_{Z;B=b}(z)$ is the probability density function (pdf) of $Z$ when $B=b$. **Important:** note that the likelihood is a function of $b$, while $z$ is just a parameter - in other words, for each value of $z$, you have a different (likelihood) function of $b$. In our case, this function takes the values
\begin{align}
L(0|Z=z) &= p_{Z;B=0}(z) = p_{Y_2}(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_2^2}}\exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2\sigma_2^2}(z-\mu_2)^2\Bigr) \\
L(1|Z=z) &= p_{Z;B=1}(z) = p_{Y_1}(z) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi\sigma_1^2}}\exp\Bigl(-\frac{1}{2\sigma_1^2}(z-\mu_1)^2\Bigr).
\end{align}
If $L(0|Z=z) > L(1|Z=z)$, we decide that $H_0$ is the true hypothesis and that $Z=Y_2$, otherwise we take $H_1$ as the true hypothesis and assume $Z=Y_1$. In practice, we can speed up things and look at the sign of the log-likelihood ratio (recall we are assuming $\mu_1>\mu_2$ and $\sigma_1^2=\sigma_2^2=\sigma^2$)
$$
\log \frac{L(1|Z=z)}{L(0|Z=z)} = \frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sigma^2}\Bigl(z-\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}\Bigr)
$$
which tells us that we should pick $H_1$ and $Z=Y_1$ when $z > (\mu_1+\mu_2)/2$.

As a side note, in this "parametric" case, we have
\begin{align}
E[X|Z]&=\begin{cases}
E[X|Y_1] &\text{if $B=1$} \\
E[X|Y_2] &\text{if $B=0$}
\end{cases} \\
&=\begin{cases}
\mu_X + \rho_{X,1}\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_1}(Y_1-\mu_1) &\text{if $B=1$} \\
\mu_X + \rho_{X,2}\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_2}(Y_2-\mu_2) &\text{if $B=0$.}
\end{cases}
\end{align}

### Case 2: $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable

For the second case, we assume $B$ is a Bernoulli random variable *independent* of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$, with $\Pr[B=1]=p$ and $\Pr[B=0]=q=1-p$. Then, we can still apply the maximum likelihood approach of before (now, even though the final expression is the same, it is common to use the notation $p_{Z|B=b}(z)$ instead of $p_{Z;B=b}(z)$, just to emphasize that we are looking at the pdf of $Z$ *conditioned* to the random variable $B$ as opposed to fixing the value of a parameter). However, by doing this, we will not take into account what we know about $B$, and a *maximum a posteriori* (MAP) approach may be a better choice: we decide that $H_1$ is the correct hypothesis and $B=1$ after observing $Z=z$ if
$$
\Pr[B=1|Z=z] > \Pr[B=0|Z=z]. \tag{1}\label{1}
$$
The a posteriori probabilities are nothing else than the probability of $B$ being either $0$ or $1$ conditioned on the observation $Z=z$. Luckily, Bayes' theorem allows us to compute them very easily:
$$
\Pr[B=b|Z=z]=\frac{p_{Z|B=b}(z)\Pr[B=b]}{p_Z(z)}.
$$
Computing the marginal pdf $p_Z(z)$ may be difficult but, as you can see, it will appear on both sides of (\ref{1}) and our MAP test can be written as
$$
p_{Z|B=1}(z)\Pr[B=1] > p_{Z|B=0}(z)\Pr[B=0]
$$
or, rearranging and taking the logarithm
$$
\log \frac{p_{Z|B=1}(z)}{p_{Z|B=0}(z)}=\frac{\mu_1-\mu_2}{\sigma^2}\Bigl(z-\frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2}\Bigr) > \log\frac{q}{p} = \log\frac{\Pr[B=0]}{\Pr[B=1]}.
$$
In other words, we decide for $H_1$ (that is $B=1$ and $Z=Y_1$) if
$$
z > \frac{\mu_1+\mu_2}{2} + \frac{\sigma^2}{\mu_1-\mu_2}\log\frac{q}{p}.
$$
When $p=q=1/2$, this approach is equivalent to the previous one. On the contrary, when $p\ne q$, we see that it suggests to move the threshold to the left (if $q<p$) or to the right (if $q>p$) - can you see why?

For completeness, it's worth mentioning here too that
\begin{align}
E[X|Z] &= \Pr[B=1]E[X|Z, B=1] + \Pr[B=0]E[X|Z, B=0] \\
&= p E[X|Y_1] + q E[X|Y_2] \\
&= \mu_X + p \rho_{X,1}\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_1}(Y_1-\mu_1) + q\rho_{X,2}\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_2}(Y_2-\mu_2)
\end{align}
very similar to what you had already derived.

### Last remarks

- This is just a very quick introduction to hypothesis testing. Other questions arise from here - for instance, what's the probability of making the correct decision? Or what's the probability of accepting $H_1$ when $H_0$ is the true hypothesis (false alarm)? I invite you to look into the subject.
- Our initial, simple assumptions about $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are that they are both normal, with the same variance but with $E[Y_1] > E[Y_2]$. Starting from there, we showed, with two different approaches, that we can pick a threshold and guess that $Z=Y_1$ when the observed value $z$ of $Z$ is larger than the threshold. If this is not enough for you, you can make the model more complex by having different variances $\sigma_1^2 \ne \sigma_2^2$ or by assuming that $B$ is not independent of $Y_1$ and $Y_2$.
- Note that, in any case, the problem of inferring $H_0$ or $H_1$ based on the observation $Z=z$ is disjoint from computing $E[X|Z]$, which only depends on the starting model. Also, just in case, note that the problem of expressing $E[X|Z]$ (a random variable) is different from the one of computing $E[X|Z=z]$ (a deterministic quantity), which does depend on the observation - but you still need a good initial model to work it out.

---

### Update

To complete the answer by satisfying [this request](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4802824/how-to-model-the-probability-function-in-a-weighted-sum-of-conditional-means#comment10223101_4805877), under the model of case 2 we have
\begin{align}
E[X|Z=z] &= \Pr[B=1]E[X|Z=z, B=1] + \Pr[B=0]E[X|Z=z, B=0] \\
&= p E[X|Y_1=z] + q E[X|Y_2=z] \\
&= \mu_X + p \rho_{X,1}\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_1}(z-\mu_1) + q\rho_{X,2}\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_2}(z-\mu_2)
\end{align}
while, for the variance,
\begin{align}
\operatorname{Var}[X|Z=z] &= E\bigl[(X-\mu_X)^2|Z=z\bigr] \\
&= p E\bigl[(X-\mu_X)^2|Z=z, B=1\bigr] + q E\bigl[(X-\mu_X)^2|Z=z, B=0\bigr] \\
&= p \operatorname{Var}\bigl[X|Y_1=z\bigr] + q \operatorname{Var}\bigl[X|Y_2=z\bigr] \\
&= p(1-\rho_{X,1}^2)\sigma_X^2 + q(1-\rho_{X,2}^2)\sigma_X^2 \\
&= (1-p\rho_{X,1}^2-q\rho_{X,2}^2)\sigma_X^2.
\end{align}
This follows from [well-known results about the conditional distribution of normal random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multivariate_normal_distribution#Bivariate_case_2):
$$
(X|Y_i=z) \sim \mathcal{N}\Bigl(\mu_X + \rho_{X,i}\frac{\sigma_X}{\sigma_i}(z-\mu_i), (1-\rho_{X,i}^2)\sigma_X^2\Bigr).
$$

Comment: Thank you - it's a great and exhaustive answer. I now realize that Case 2 captures my scenario almost exactly: in my case $\sigma_1^2\neq\sigma_2^2$. I read your answer just now, so I am still trying to understand all the details. First of all, a related question would be: what is $Var[X|BY_1+(1−B)Y_2]$? I don't think that is just $pVar[X|Y_1]+(1-p)Var[X|Y_2]$ when $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are correlated, or is it?

Comment: Also, in the final part you write “the problem of expressing $E[X|Z]$ (a random variable) is different from the one of computing $E[X|Z=z]$ (a deterministic quantity), which does depend on the observation”, which I totally agree too. But how to express $E[X|Z=z]$ then? I know that it is strictly related to the probabilities in the Bayes calculation you do before, but I am not sure how to proceed and get the whole picture. Maybe you can enrich your answer with the $E[X|Z=z]$ and $Var[X|Z]$ and $Var[X|Z=z]$ calculations (for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ correlated)? I’d give best answer.

Comment: Please correct me if I am wrong: $E[X|Z=z] = E[X|B=1, Y_1 = z] * p + E[X|B=0, Y_2 = z] * (1 - p)$ with $E[X|B=1, Y_1 = z] = μ_X + ρ_X,1 * (σ_X/σ_1) * (z - μ_1) $ and $E[X|B=0, Y_2 = z] = μ_X + ρ_X,2 * (σ_X/σ_2) * (z - μ_2)$. Then $Var[X|Z=z] = Var[X|B=1, Y_1 = z] * p + Var[X|B=0, Y_2 = z] * (1 - p)$ with $Var[X|B=1, Y_1 = z] = σ_X^2 * (1 - ρ_X,1^2) + ρ_Y^2 * (z - μ_1)^2 * σ_X^2 / σ_1^2$ and $Var[X|B=0, Y_2 = z] = σ_X^2 * (1 - ρ_X,2^2) + ρ_Y^2 * (z - μ_2)^2 * σ_X^2 / σ_2^2$…I am not confident with these calculations.. so please add yours to the answer 

Comment: The expected values are OK, but not the variance - you have an extra term $\rho_Y^2 (z-\mu_i)^2\sigma_X^2/\sigma_i^2$... what is $\rho_Y$ anyway? I've edited the answer with the new request.

Comment: In the first equality you are assuming that $E[X|B=1,Z=z]=E[X|B=1,Y_1=z]$, which is not true.

Comment: Speltzu you disagree with the updated answer? @dvdgrgrtt $rho_Y$ would be a newly introduced correlation between $Y_1$ and $Y_2$. How would it enter the conditional variance? Notice that $Z$ is either $Y_1$ or $Y_2$ because of the Bernoulli $B$ but inferring one or the other from observation $z$ might tell me something about what $Z$ could have been …

Comment: I now think that the correlation between $Y_1 $and $Y_2$ doesn’t matter for the conditional mean and variance of $X$ given $Z$ (but only the correlations between $X$ and $Y_1$ and $X$ and $Y_2$).

Comment: IMHO, once you condition on $B$ being either $0$ or $1$, you have either $Z=Y_2$ or $Z=Y_1$, respectively, and there's no need to consider the correlation between the two. Also, note that there is no inference here - we are just computing $E[X|Z=z]$ based on the "Bernoulli model" above, where $\Pr[B=1]$ is given. — I've just read your comment while writing this one: exactly, it doesn't matter.

Comment: The same error that I pointed out before is made in the update.

Comment: @Speltzu how would you adjust the calculations?

Comment: I don't know, but the truth is that the equalities referring to the mean and variance are not correct. As a counterexample you can take $X,Y,B$ independent of each other and $Y_1=X, Y_2=Y$.

Answer (score 0):

That $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ are normally distributed and mutually exclusive is contradictory:
$$1=P(Y_1\in R \cap  Y_2\in R)=P((Y_1=0\cup Y_1\neq 0) \cap  (Y_2=0\cup Y_2\neq 0))=$$
$$=P(Y_1=0 \cap  Y_2=0)+P(Y_1=0 \cap  Y_2\neq 0)+P(Y_1\neq 0 \cap  Y_2=0)+ P(Y_1\neq 0 \cap  Y_2\neq 0)=0$$

Comment: I think my wording of the question is very confusing. What I meant by “mutually exclusive” is exactly what @dvdgrgrtt formalised with the Bernoulli RV: $Z=BY_1+(1−B)Y_2$. But now I am stuck with the conditional variance $Var[X|Z]$ for $Y_1$ and $Y_2$ correlated…